# Cannot set cookie with Nest.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cookies, nestjs

I have created `/sign-in` endpoint that basically returns object with 2 tokens - refresh token and access token.

```
@Post('/sign-in')
signIn(@Body() signInUserDto: SignInUserDto): Promise<TokensDto> {
  return this.userService.signIn(signInUserDto);
}
```

What I want to do, is to send access token normally as `JSON`, but send access token as cookie, so I changed a little bit this function and made it look like this.

```
@Post('/sign-in')
async signIn(
  @Request() req: ExpressRequest,
  @Response() res: ExpressResponse
): Promise<ExpressResponse<any, Record<string, any>>> {
  const { _at, _rt } = await this.userService.signIn(req.body);
  res.cookie('_rt', _rt, {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'strict',
    maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  });
  return res.status(200).json({ _at });
}
```

As a result, I get access token in response, but I don't get refresh token in cookie. Right away I can tell, that on front-end I have `withCredentials: true` in axios. Also, when I send request to this endpoint with postman, I get cookie, but not on front-end. Why it happens and how I can make it set cookie?

**PS.**

In server terminal, no matter how I send request, from front-end or postman, I get this warning:

```
Error [ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION]: This is caused by either a bug in Node.js or incorrect usage of Node.js internals.
Please open an issue with this stack trace at https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues

    at assert (internal/assert.js:14:11)
    at ServerResponse.detachSocket (_http_server.js:223:3)
    at resOnFinish (_http_server.js:685:7)
    at ServerResponse.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at onFinish (_http_outgoing.js:735:10)
    at onCorkedFinish (_stream_writable.js:673:5)
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:490:5)
    at afterWriteTick (_stream_writable.js:477:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21)
```

Comment: How are you checking if you have the cookie on the front end? Have you checked the response headers for a `Set-Cookie` header?

Comment: I check it in Application/Cookies in devtools.

Comment: What about the response headers?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Actually, nothing, but here you go. ```Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 282
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 12 Aug 2022 06:24:20 GMT
ETag: "ho9ctu0n8u7u"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: Hmm, okay, so cookie definitely isn't sent back. That error in your terminal looks interesting, is there anymore to it?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel By the way, I have an idea, why it happens, after click on button I send request 'twice'. First time is when service sends request to `Next.js` endpoint (folder structure describes routes, as you know), and the second one, when this endpoint sends this request to server. And at this second request is place, where I should put cookie, but as response type I have `NextApiResponse` and this type has no cookie field.

Comment: Okay, that sounds like an issue with Next not forwarding on the cookie, not that Nest (or rather express) isn't sending the cookie in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem, but only partly.

The problem was with front-end, not back-end, because, as I said before, I was able, using postman, to get cookie from server.

And here is the issue.

First of all, you need to install 2 packages `cookie` and `@types/cookie`, than, in route (as we remember, routing in `Next.js` works as folder structure in project), you need to import serialize from installed package:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { AxiosError } from "axios";
import { api } from "../../../api";
import { serialize } from 'cookie'

export default async (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.post('/user/sign-in', req.body)

    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', serialize('_rt', data.data._rt, {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: 'strict',
      maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    }))
    return res.json(data)
  } catch (error) {
    return res
      .status((error as AxiosError).response?.status as number)
      .json((error as AxiosError).response?.data);
  }
}
```

And as a result, in response, you can see `Set-Cookie` header with cookie, but, that's why it resolved partly, I don't see this cookie in devtools in `Application/Cookies` section.